# Trying to display Uppy uploader within a simple_from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, simple-form-for

I have successfully managed to include the uppy uploader by adding a class called "dashboard-container" to simple_form's `input[type=file]` class list but my uploader doesn't display within the field.

As you can see from the console it is being loaded properly but the default "Choose file" button is still being rendered and there must be a conflict somewhere.

I am also managing to play with the simple_form css and my dashboard-container class as well, as you can see I've added a bit of radius from simple_form scss itself and some black border from my dashboard container.

[Results from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X93FK.png)

Here's my simple_form code:

```
<div id="new_flat_form_container">
    <div id="new_flat_form">
        <%= simple_form_for flat do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :title, label: "Titre", hint:"Quelques mots pour décrire votre logement" %>
        <%= f.input :category, label: "Catégorie", collection: ["maison", "appartement", "terrain", "caravane", "camping-car"]%>
        <%= f.input :description, as: :text %>
        <%= f.input :nb_of_bathrooms, label: "Nombre de salles de bain", input_html: {class: 'form-control btn-lg col-sm-6'}, collection:1..5 %>
        <%= f.input :photos, as: :file, multiple: true,direct_upload: true %>
        <%= f.input :price_per_night, label: "Prix par nuit, en DU", hint:"A exprimer en DU pour nous habituer à compter ainsi"%>
        <div class="row">
            <%= f.button :submit, value: "Je crée mon logement", class:"btn btn-success col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

The repo is here: https://github.com/thomasbromehead/log1/tree/simple_form

I would greatly appreciate some help.
I am on Rails 5.2 and Webpack 3.12

Comment: does it work if you click on the "Choose file" button, are there any logs if it doesn't?

Comment: @JohnBaker: apparently Uppy uses the default file_field but hides it so it does need to be there. Didn't implement it but reading other's code that's what I understood. Tried using this with Shrine and S3 but more than I can handle right now ;) Thanks for trying to help and to answer you, yes the button worked but Uppy wasn't displayed as I wasn't calling it properly in the JS.

Answer (score 2):

So if you're using Webpacker to handle your Webpack config, this setup worked for me:

```
import Uppy from '@uppy/core'
import Dashboard from '@uppy/dashboard'

const uppy = Uppy({
  id: 'yourIdName',
})
  .use(Dashboard, {
    target: '#your-target-element',
    replaceTargetContent: true,
    inline: true,
  })

uppy.on('complete', (result) => {
  console.log('Upload complete! We’ve uploaded these files:', result.successful)
})
```

The important values here are the `replaceTargetContent` and `inline` properties. `inline` displays the Dashboard in the target element instead of as a modal, and `replaceTargetContent` does what it says, putting the Dashboard inside your target instead of whatever content (ie. a form field) was there before.

Uppy docs to refer are here:

https://uppy.io/docs/dashboard/#inline-false

https://uppy.io/docs/dashboard/#replaceTargetContent-false